# C++ Inheritance change member

Tags: c++, inheritance

Currently learning more c++ and I have this question: Why do I have to use a function to change a member of a parent class instead of just changing it without the function?

```
class Shape{
private: 
  int a;
protected:
  int b;
public:
  int c;
};

class Rectangle: public Shape{
public:
  c = 123;
  void change_c(){c = 321;}
};
```

Comment: C++ program exceution happens in functions. A program cannot do anything without functions. (initialiser of a static object is perhaps an exception).

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking here. Since `c` is public, it can be changed externally by a function which is not a method of the class.

Comment: These two answered my question perfectly. I just had a "duhh" moment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a value to a variable, like in the statement `c = 123;`, is illegal outside of a variable declaration or an assignment performed within a function.  Which means you can't perform it from within the class scope of a derived class:

```
class Rectangle: public Shape{
public:
  c = 123; // <-- illegal
  int d = 123; // <-- OK, in C++11 and later
  Rectangle() { c = 321; } // <-- OK
  void change_c(){ c = 321; } // <-- OK
}
```